# Is the reviewer the journal manager?

Tags: peer-review, journals

I submitted a manuscript to a journal, and the feedback I received required major revisions. Interestingly, I noticed that the system indicates that one of the reviewers is the journal manager. What does this mean? Previously, this manuscript had been on hold for seven months without finding a reviewer. Was it reviewed by internal journal staff?

What kind of position is a journal manager?

[image]

Comment: "I noticed that the system indicates that one of the reviewers is the journal manager." No, it does not. It indicates that the report was *uploaded* by a "journal manager".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Journal manager" sounds like a member of the journal staff. They are not expected to review the paper. Since they uploaded the report, one of two possibilities suggest themselves:

1. The reviewer sent the report to them directly (e.g. via email), and they are uploading the report on the reviewer's behalf.
2. The review originally had some problem which the journal manager fixed, and this requires them to upload a new report. Examples could be, the reviewer forgot something, the report is poorly formatted, the report included identifying information of the reviewer and the journal manager is anonymizing, etc.

Comment: In some cases, a journal manager may be an academic as well, and may occasionally review manuscripts.  But (as noted) you cannot make that conclusion from the information shown in the OP.